# How do I incorporate MERGE into my SSIS Data Flow Task?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to prevent duplicates when I'm inserting values from a staging table into the primary table. I only have two components: an `OLE DB SOURCE` which points to an `OLE DB DESTINATION`.

In the `OLE DB SOURCE`, I originally had this:

```
SELECT [QVW Names] as 'QVW Name', '1' as 'QVW Type'
FROM dbo.STG_QVD_Generator
WHERE [QVW Names] <> ''
UNION
SELECT [QVW Names] as 'QVW Name', '2' as 'QVW Type'
FROM dbo.STG_Data_Models
WHERE [QVW Names] <> ''
```

To prevent the duplicates, I researched and began testing out a new query by using SQL Server Management Studio, I was able to get this:

```
MERGE INTO QVW_Files AS tbl 
USING (SELECT [QVW Names] as 'QVW Name', '1' as 'QVW Type'
       FROM dbo.STG_QVD_Generator
       WHERE [QVW Names] <> ''
       UNION
       SELECT [QVW Names] as 'QVW Name', '2' as 'QVW Type'
       FROM dbo.STG_Data_Models
       WHERE [QVW Names] <> '') AS src 
ON (tbl.QVW_Name = src.[QVW Name] AND tbl.QVW_Type_ID = src.[QVW Type]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (QVW_Name, QVW_Type_ID) 
    VALUES (src.[QVW Name], src.[QVW Type]);
```

and it seems to prevent duplicates from being entered into the target tables from the staging tables. However, I entered this into my `OLE DB SOURCE` and I realized that it would return no columns because this is not really a SELECT statement. How can I incorporate it into my Data Flow Task?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use `Execute SQL Task` on control flow with your statement.

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov, that's a pretty good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS 2012 - Insert new rows, ignore existing rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011049/ssis-2012-insert-new-rows-ignore-existing-rows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Merge or Merge Join Transformation in SSIS. Create a Data Flow Task, setup each of your source tables as OLE DB Source objects, and then use Merge or Merge Join, and then set your Destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a SQL task to do the merge. Add it after your data flow.